# How to get the url from <media:content> in a RSS feed using SimplePie

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplepie

I'm trying to use SimplePie and PHP to grab the url value from the  tag. An example of the RSS code is:

```
<item>
  <title>Headline goes here</title>
  <link>https://sampledomain.com/index.html</link>
  <description><![CDATA[ Body copy is here. ]]></description>
  <dc:creator>Migraine Team</dc:creator>
  <pubDate>Mon, 29 Jul 2019 16:00:01 +0000</pubDate>
  <media:content url="https://sampledomain.net/imagetograb.jpg" medium="image"/>
  <guid>https://sampledomain.com/index.html</guid>
</item>
```

I loop through the items…

```php
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {

}
```

but I'm uncertain how to grab the url value from the  tag.

Comment: Hint: `media:content` is the tag and url value the attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574448/simplepie-and-get-item-tags-attribute

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/how_to_display_a_single_feed_item), `$item->get_link()` might be what you're looking for? Otherwise, telling us which tag would probably be helpful.

Comment: I want to access the URL attribute from the <media:content> tag.

Answer (score 4):

This is what eventually worked for me:

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {
  $item->get_item_tags('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/','content')[0]['attribs']['']['url'];
}
```